# Photos app having difficulty detecting one particular face

Tags: photos.app

There's a person in my photos library that Photos seems unable to detect and tag.

I've tagged almost 100 pictures of this person manually, yet Photos never suggests them as a possible match, or even detects their face at all. This happens with photos that were taken only seconds apart, or even black and white copies of identical color photos – things that would seem easy for it to detect.

Meanwhile, for other people in my library, I only need to tag as few as three or four photos for Photos to start suggesting them as matches. Yet even with dozens of clear, sharp, near-identical photos of this one person, it won't ever seem to recognize or suggest them.

Is it possible something is corrupted, and/or can I force Photos to reanalyze from scratch?

Comment: Maybe it [thinks this person is a gorilla](http://www.news.com.au/technology/online/black-friends-furious-after-google-photos-app-tags-them-as-gorillas/news-story/97bc0871bc5858160cb4df601324c172)? Guessing you'll just have to contact Apple Support.